# How to navigate a map with Selenium via clicking and dragging

Tags: java, selenium, google-maps, automation

I am using Selenium and Java to try and automate some google maps navigation. I want to click and hold on the map, then move to a certain direction, then release the cursor. This should move the map across the page.

So far I have

```
WebElement canvasElement = driver.findElement(map);
Actions builder = new Actions(driver.getWebDriver());
builder.moveToElement(canvasElement).clickAndHold().moveByOffset(300, 0).release().perform();
```

However, nothing on the page moves. I know I am selecting the map correctly since if I just do

```
    builder.moveToElement(canvasElement).clickAndHold().moveByOffset(300, 0).perform();
```

then when I do mouse over the map, the map moves without me having to click the left mouse button because it is still in the click and hold state and never released. Not sure why the moveByOffset is not working for this particular case. Any suggestions would be great

Comment: Did you try `dragAndDropBy()`?

Comment: Yes I tried something like 
`builder.dragAndDrop(canvasElement, driver.findElement(By.className("asdf"))).perform();`
to see if it could drag to a random element elsewhere on the page but it did nothing as well. The closest I got was what i mentioned above where it would click and hold on the canvas/map, but wouldn't move

Answer (score 0):

To click and hold on the map, then move to a certain direction, then release the cursor, one you create the chain of actions, you need to invoke the `build()` method as well and you can use the following solution:'

```
WebElement canvasElement = driver.findElement(map);
new Actions(driver).moveToElement(canvasElement, 0, 0).clickAndHold().moveByOffset(300, 0).release().build().perform();
```

Comment: It still does not work, I believe I tried that combination before.

Comment: `build()` is already invoked in `perform()`, and adding offset of 0 doesn't do anything.

Comment: @Guy Now you are disappointing me. There isn't a _...offset of 0..._ as such, but offset of `(0,0)`. But your comment _...doesn't do anything..._ surprises me the most. I still believe you understand canvas, which OP is dealing with.

Comment: What do you think `moveToElement(canvasElement, 0, 0)` does? `Moves the mouse to an offset from the center of the element.`. If you give `0, 0` it doesn't move the cruiser. It also has `return moveInTicks(target, xOffset, yOffset);`, which in that case is exactly the same as `moveToElement(canvasElement)`, `return moveInTicks(target, 0, 0);`.

Comment: I've tried those variations with no success. Closest I've gotten is what I listed in the original post where it clicks but doesn't move or release the map.

Comment: @DebanjanB turns out I got some code working but only on firefox... the exact same code does not work on chrome. Strange